# Prevent Feign from adding a trailing slash to the URL

Tags: spring-cloud-feign, feign

I am trying to retrieve an online image content in a Spring Boot application by using the below Feign client.

```
@FeignClient(name = "image")
public interface ImageClient {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    byte[] getContent(URI uri) throws WebException;

}
```

The issue that I have is that when I call the getContent method with an URL such as https://images.foo.com/1234567/5c5a7f14-d5d4-4a79-9c2e-78fed8b738c5.jpeg?foo=123, the HTTP call is made to https://images.foo.com/1234567/5c5a7f14-d5d4-4a79-9c2e-78fed8b738c5.jpeg/?foo=123 and I get an error from the server.

Is there any way to prevent Feign from adding a slash before the query parameters ?

Comment: Kindly, did you find any solution for this? I'm facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

to avoid that
divide the URL

```
@FeignClient(name = "image" ,value url = "BASE")
public interface ImageClient {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET ,value  = "X" )
    byte[] getContent(URI uri) throws WebException;

}
```

final is B/X no trailing / added

Answer (score 0):

You can also

```
@FeignClient(name = "image" ,  url = "BASE") 
public interface ImageClient {

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET   )
byte[] getContent(URI uri) throws WebException;

}
```